# Python - Reading files from Directory without single quotes

Tags: python, string, directory

I am wondering if there is a way to read in files from your directory without single quotes around them. My directory has several geodataframes with the same suffix. I can read them all in and append to a list but the list will contain single quotes around each DataFrame name, making it a str.

```
dir()
 'sub_geo_group_mangrove',
 'sub_geo_group_marsh',
 'sub_geo_group_multipolygon',
 'sub_geo_group_pan',
 'sub_geo_group_reedbed'
```

I am using these files to insert into a loop and therefore need the file names themselves without the single quotes

**Edit**

The data frames are all formatted as such:

```
sub_geo_group_mangrove.head(2)

    geometry    wetland
43  MULTIPOLYGON (((12.41310 -6.10921, 12.41274 -6...   mangrove
59  POLYGON ((12.30671 -6.15770, 12.30654 -6.15741...   mangrove
```

And I am attempting to read each DataFrame into the following lines:

[image]

Comment: where is  the data of each dataframe stored?

Comment: A filename will always be a string on it's own. That doesn't stop you using it appropriately: e.g. reading it with pandas (since you mention dataframes).

Comment: It is not stored anywhere. I create the geodataframes earlier in the script and then try to call them again.

Comment: So if I understand you correct you want to use DataFrames, which are stored in the program but all you have is their names in string format?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact structure of the dictionary you are taking about.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, it has been edited @RishabhKumar

Comment: Hi, try not to include images of your code or error. Its against SO norm. Keep things as text that can be kept as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure, what you are trying to achieve here, would have been really not necessary. But I would just answer what you ask and based on what I understand about your requirements.

As, you are trying to use the dataframe names in a loop structure I am assuming that the dataframes are available in the loop's scope.

which you have shown using `dir()` command in your example.

From python docs:

> dir(...)
> dir([object]) -> list of strings
>
> If called without an argument, return the names in the current scope.

Now let's assume the list in which your DataFrame names are present is

```
dfnames = ['sub_geo_group_mangrove','sub_geo_group_marsh','sub_geo_group_multipolygon',...]
```

Based on what I understand about the problem you mentioned:

Now to loop over them you are not able to do something like:

```
for df in dfnames:

    #do something with this df
```

cause the `type(df)` would be string.

At this point you can do couple of things. The most optimal of that, I think would be:

```
for name in dfnames:
    df = vars()[name]

    # do something with this df
```

`vars()` without argument is similar to `locals()`.

`vars()` returns a dictionary, of variables used in your local scope.

The keys in this dictionary is variable names in string type, and the values associated with them is the data associated to those variables.